# Stopping Apple Watch Workout when wet

Tags: apple-watch

Frequently I cannot stop the timer for a run in the Workout app if I am too sweaty - the touch screen does not recognize my finger press, and neither the side button or Digital Crown help.

Is there a combination of buttons or maybe even gestures that can be used to stop the timer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, pause the workout by pressing the crown and side button **at the same time** (here's an example taken from a swimming workout).

[image]

This will pause the workout until you can dry your fingers.  An unfortunate side-effect of pressing these buttons will be that a screenshot will be taken *if* you also turned on the feature to take a screenshot when these buttons are pressed.

After your fingers are dry, you can end the workout in the normal manner by swiping to the right and tapping End.

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are connected to the Internet via iPhone or cellular watch, you can also use Siri to stop the workout - just say "**Stop Workout**".  Note that you can ask Siri other things like "**Start Swim**" or "**Add run**" to start a run after a swim for example. I used it on an 18k SwimRun this year with 7 swims and 8 runs, and used Siri to change sport throughout - worked great!